# How to make sure a Private DNS zone is resolving a given private ip?

Tags: azure-private-dns, azure-private-dns-zone

The use case scenario here is that the private DNS resolves an internal IP acting as the default gateway of an API Manager - APIM.

In front of APIM, there is an Application Gateway with a backend pool targeting the private DNS.

I can see that the backend health status is `unknown`, and it might be related to the FQDN - associated with an internal Ip, not being resolved, but how can I make sure that it is the actual problem?

- **I'd rather not have to create a whole VM just to ping it by name.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try either of the following ways to make sure Private DNS zone is resolving a given private IP.

> **Workaround 1:**
>
> 1. Create an Azure VNet with a DNS private zone like private.test.com.
> 2. Create a VM and a VPN gateway on that VNet. Enable VNet integration.
> 3. with my Azure web app service.
>
> **Workaround 2:**
>
> 1. [Deploy new Azure Private DNS Zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/catalog-private-link-name-resolution#option-1---deploy-new-azure-private-dns-zones)
>    in your Azure environment part of private endpoint deployment.
>    (Default option)
> 2. [Use existing Azure Private DNS Zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/catalog-private-link-name-resolution#option-2---use-existing-azure-private-dns-zones).
>    Use this option if you using a private endpoint in a hub-and-spoke
>    model from a different subscription or even within the same
>    subscription.
> 3. [Use your own DNS Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/catalog-private-link-name-resolution#option-3---use-your-own-dns-servers)
>    if you do not use DNS forwarders and instead you manage A records
>    directly in your on-premises DNS servers.

Reference: [Azure DNS zone record not resolving to specified IP from App service to Virtual Machine - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55279599/azure-dns-zone-record-not-resolving-to-specified-ip-from-app-service-to-virtual) and [Configure DNS Name Resolution for private endpoints - Azure Purview | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/catalog-private-link-name-resolution)